# Update attendees using the eventbrite API?

Tags: api, updates, eventbrite

I really need to update info for some of the attendees of my eventbrite event, (on the order of a couple hundred), and I don't want to do it by hand. Is there a way I can use the eventbrite API to update a user? It doesn't need to be the official API, if there's a hack-y solution using their private API that would work for me. I just really need a way to programmatically update the data for these attendees.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Eventbrite doesn't allow for attendees to be added to an event via an API.